# Scala Case Class serialization

Tags: scala, exception, serialization, case-class

I've been trying to binary serialize a composite case class object that kept throwing a weird exception. I don't really understand what is wrong with this example which throws the following exception. I used to get that exception for circular references which is not the case here. Some hints please?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field com.Table.rows of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of com.Table
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field com.Table.rows of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of com.Table
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2024)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at com.TestSeri$.serializeBinDeserialise(TestSeri.scala:37)
    at com.TestSeri$.main(TestSeri.scala:22)
    at com.TestSeri.main(TestSeri.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Here is the code

```
import java.io._    
import scalax.file.Path

case class Row(name: String)
case class Table(rows: List[Row])
case class Cont(docs: Map[String, Table])

case object TestSeri {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cc = Cont(docs = List(
      "1" -> Table(rows = List(Row("r1"), Row("r2"))),
      "2" -> Table(rows = List(Row("r301"), Row("r31"), Row("r32")))
    ).toMap)

    val tt = Table(rows = List(Row("r1"), Row("r2")))
    val ttdes = serializeBinDeserialize(tt)
    println(ttdes == tt)

    val ccdes = serializeBinDeserialize(cc)
    println(ccdes == cc)
  }

  def serializeBinDeserialize[T](payload: T): T = {
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
    out.writeObject(payload)

    val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray)
    val in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)
    in.readObject().asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well for me, no exception, printing `true` for both checks. I'm using Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: yes indeed. with scalac it runs correctly. it fails only with sbt ... weird

Comment: In SBT do you have something like `fork in Test := true`?

Comment: No. I had `fork in run := false` but i deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing List with Array which is immutable too, fixed the problem. 
In my original problem I had a Map which I replaced with TreeMap.

I think is likely to be related to the proxy pattern implementation in generic immutable List and Map mentioned here:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9237.

Can't believe I wasted a full day on this.